# Animacion Borde de CSS para boton estado Hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, animacion-css

estoy intentando hacer una animación en css que consta en que aparezca una linea de izquierda a derecha y se detenga la animación con la linea completa en la parte inferior del botón donde tengo el mouse.
Nose como hacer que aparezca la linea de izquierda a derecha y permanezca allí hasta que el estado Hover se desactive en el bóton.
Lo que he hecho hasta el momento es que aparezca la linea y permanezca pero sin la animación de movimiento.

Quiero que la linea aparezca desde la izquierda en la parte inferior y se vuelva más grande hacia la derecha y cuando este completo con respecto al boton permanezca allí hasta que el estado Hover del boton se desactive.

La referencia de donde vi esa animacion implementada es de aqui:
https://rubiuscorp.com/

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav div ul li a {
    color: black;
    font-size:18.3px;
    letter-spacing: 0,1px;
    font-family: Din-Regular;
}

nav div ul li a:hover {
    color:#efb810;


    border-bottom: 2px solid currentColor;
    transition: right 0.3s ease;
    transition-property: right;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    z-index: 6;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Din-Regular;
        src: url(../font/DINNextLTPro-Regular.ttf); 
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GLUCK</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

<body>

  <!--MENU FIXED TOP-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid px-5">
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="index.html">
        <img src="img/logoEmpresa.svg" alt="imagen corporativa" width="35px" height="35px">
      </a> 
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-light" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>  

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <!--IZQ-->
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">INICIO</a>
          </li> 
        </ul>
        <!--DERECHA-->
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="html/diseño.html">DISEÑO</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="html/sublimacion.html">SUBLIMACION</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="html/contacto.html">CONTACTO</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </nav>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando la etiqueta before en el elemento que quieras estilizar

```
    nav div ul li a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid currentColor;
    transition: right 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 6;
}
```

Comment: No, lo coloque con before y ahora no me aparece la linea inferior.

Answer (score 0):

La transición no tiene forma de saber de forma morfológica como debe ser el cambio entre un antes y después si en el código no está especificado.

Lo que sucede es que tienes un elemento sin borde inferior, luego tienes uno con borde inferior, lo más que se podría inferir es hacer una animación de "fade in" aparecer suave. Por ello si lo que deseas es una animación de izquierda a derecha debes poner un mismo elemento con ancho 0% y al activar `:hover` tenga el 100%.

Como al borde no se le puede poner porcentaje al ancho, he puesto un elemento adicional 'before' en forma de borde, que cumple lo anterior.

Adicionalmente el elemento padre(.parent) le he puesto position: relative, ya que me estaba poniendo el bottom a lo más abajo del div inicial. Desconozco porqué, he tanteado sospechando que pudo ser por eso.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav div ul li {
    position: relative;
}

nav div ul li a {
    color: black;
    font-size:18.3px;
    letter-spacing: 0,1px;
    font-family: Din-Regular;
}

   nav div ul li a:before {
  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  height  : 5px;
  width   : 0%;  /* or 100px */
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
}

   nav div ul li a:hover:before {
  width   : 100%;  /* or 100px */
  transition: 1s;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Din-Regular;
        src: url(../font/DINNextLTPro-Regular.ttf); 
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GLUCK</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

<body>

  <!--MENU FIXED TOP-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid px-5">
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="index.html">
        <img src="img/logoEmpresa.svg" alt="imagen corporativa" width="35px" height="35px">
      </a> 
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-light" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>  

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <!--IZQ-->
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">INICIO</a>
          </li> 
        </ul>
        <!--DERECHA-->
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="html/diseño.html">DISEÑO</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="html/sublimacion.html">SUBLIMACION</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="html/contacto.html">CONTACTO</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </nav>

  </body>
</html>
```